# Mac OS X Safari/Wi-Fi connectivity issue

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, safari

I'm using a MacBook Air and after a few issues with my internet line, I have some problems with my connectivity. When I connect to my Wi-Fi, everything seems ok, but when I try web browsing using Safari or launch WoW, they behave as if there was no internet connection. On the other hand, some other apps like Chrome, Mumble, or Minecraft work perfectly.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a possible DNS issue.  Are you able to ping domain names?  Go into Utilities->Network Utility and try pinging www.cisco.com

The other tabs contain tools that further help in diagnosing the problem.  Let us know how it goes....

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X has two separate DNS resolver libraries built into it. There's the traditional Unix one that Unix tools, open-source apps, cross-platform apps, and Java apps are likely to use, and there's the one that goes through Bonjour's mDNSResponder process, that's used by most of the built-in GUI apps in Mac OS X and most Mac-specific Cocoa apps.

When mDNSResponder's ability to do DNS lookups chokes, Apple apps and Cocoa apps won't be able to do DNS lookups, whereas certain third-party apps and unix tools that use the old fashioned Unix system calls for doing DNS lookups will still function.

To get mDNSResponder unstuck, I recommend killing it and letting `launchd` automatically relaunch it. `launchd` is Mac OS X's primary built-in mechanism for autolaunching and relaunching background processes and other things that need to be launched.

```
sudo killall mDNSResponder
```